# Omnigraffle: How do I export all top-level groups on a canvas to separate images?

Tags: user-experience

In short, I have a single canvas with many top-level group objects (some of which contain sub-groups). Is there a plugin/script that will automatically export all of of these top-level groups to separate images in X format?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those with the same problem, I found an AppleScript that achieves the basic functionality required.

http://sunnyinsight.blogspot.com/2009/08/applescripting-with-omnigraffle.html